# json file load issue using Python

Tags: python, json, load

I was try to dump and load dictionary to json file using Python. I can dump file without a problem. However, when i try to load file into temp dictionary, error occur. I can not figure out the issue, Can anyone can help me on this ?Thanks

```
import os
import json

def get_stored_birth():
    filename ='C:/Users/Sam/name.json'
    temp = {}

    with open(filename,'r+') as f_obj1:
        temp =json.load(f_obj1)
        print(temp.get(name),"is the birthday of",name)

def get_new_birth():
    birth=str(input())
    my_dict[name]=birth
    print("Birthday database updated")      
    filename ='C:/Users/Sam/name.json'
    with open(filename,'a') as f_obj:
            f_obj.write('\n')
            json.dump(my_dict,f_obj) 
    return name

my_dict={}

def quit():
   """This function quit program"""  
   return quit

while True:
    filename ='C:/Users/Sam/name.json'
    print("Enter a name:(blank to quit)")
    name= str(input())
    if name=="":              
        exit()

    if name in my_dict:
         name= get_stored_birth()
    else:
        print("I dont have info for",name)
        print("What is their birthday")
        name= get_new_birth()
```

The traceback as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


     File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Tianxu_Assignment2\Assignment 2.py", line 45, in <module>
        name= get_stored_birth()
      File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Tianxu_Assignment2\Assignment 2.py", line 10, in get_stored_birth
        temp =json.load(f_obj1)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 12)
```

Comment: can you post json file?

Comment: You can't append multiple JSON objects to a file. `json.load()` expects the file to contain a single JSON object.

Comment: If you want to add items to the file, you need to load the file into a dictionary, add a new element to the dictionary, then rewrite the file.

Comment: hi barmar, i think other people did same way. load json to empty dictionary and print it out. i dont know why my doest work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved !!!
1. replace with open(filename, 'a') as f_obj with replace with open(filename, 'w')
2. 
    if name in my_dict: 
    should not check my_dict !!! every time start a program will use new "dictionary". I move 
filename ='C:/Users/Sam/name.json'
    temp = {}

```
with open(filename,'r+') as f_obj1:
    temp =json.load(f_obj1)
```

to main loop and check if name in temp:

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are appending new json to previous jsons you have created. Just substitute this line: 
    `with open(filename,'a') as f_obj:`
with this one:
    `with open(filename,'w') as f_obj:`

Comment: Thank mohammad. i change filename ,"a" with a " w". The program never gets error again, but it still can not load json file to dictionary.